# @command decorator not working on discord.py

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py

My discord bot connects just fine, event on_ready is working with no problems. However when I call any of the commands declared with @bot.command, the bot doesn't recognize the message as a command (at least that's what I think it's happening).

Code:

```
import discord
import pickle

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot

token = ""
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', case_insensitive=True, intents=discord.Intents.default())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))


@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    print('received')
    await ctx.send('msg received')


bot.run(token)
```

That's pretty much it, when I run it the bot connects just fine, but the !test command doesn't work.
Let me know if I didn't add important information, first time asking something here.

EDIT: It's working locally, it doesn't work when it's being hosted on heroku (bot connects and is online, doesn't recognize commands).

Requirements file:

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
discord~=1.7.3
setuptools~=60.2.0
```

Comment: The provided code looks okay. Have you an `on_message` event defined in the code?

Comment: No, but when I tried to use it it said the message var was empty when I tried to make the bot send its content.

Comment: I managed to fix it, it was a problem with the hosting build pack actually. Just added the discord package version to the requirements file and removed the direct github link and it fixed my issue. Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: Great! Also just be aware that if you ever update in the future you will need to enable the `message_content` intent (and you'll be forced to in 15 days)